# WebSocket connection to 'wss://argus.chi.shopify.io' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, shopify

I'm getting the below warning in the console when navigating to my Shopify Rails app:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://argus.chi.shopify.io' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

Can someone explain what this means and why it might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

The host `argus.chi.shopify.io` did not respond when I did `ping` it. Check whether the host is running or not.

Comment: Weird, I don't even know what argus.chi.shopify.io is. Nothing to do with my side.